# Example of IBM Watson Conversation API client in c#/.net

Tags: c#, rest, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson

I am new to this technology, but I want to use Watson's API conversation in a .NET application. How can I call Watson Cloud Services in .NET?

Comment: Please post this on the Spanish site instead. This site is English only.

Comment: Por favor preguntarlo [aqui](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: To be clear though, this would be a bad question and still unclear or overbroad were it asked in English.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions you run into while using programming tools, not for recommendations about how to use the tools. For tips on which questions to ask here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. For code examples, check out the usual suspects: GitHub or the vendor's tutorials and enablement at https://developer.ibm.com or the product documentation at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/

Comment: Ok, let's get there... :) does it sound better now?

Comment: For official response: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/284053/watson-net-sdk.html

Comment: There is an official [.NET Standard SDK for Watson Services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk). It is still in Beta but is actively being developed.

Comment: @ralphearle, what else does it take to have you reverse your downvote on this?

Comment: @Rbjz, I am retired from IBM and no longer active on Stack Overflow. When I was monitoring the Bluemix questions I made it a practice of never down voting questions unless they were abusive or not about programming . I did add comments to explain why questions were getting down voted, so that people understood what was involved. I have no memory of down-voting your question, and I checked a record of my votes and do not see evidence of it. Can I ask you in return, why is it important to you to have down-votes changed?

Comment: @ralphearle, thanks for your explanation.Very well if it's not your downvote, I could only guess... I think this question (which is not mine btw.) is worth answering (mine is the answer) for the lack of simple examples on using the API. I think we can make this question stand up to the SO standards rather than burry it in downvotes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think IBM has a rather far remote understanding of 'simple'. Their [sample apps](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/sample-applications.html) are rather obscure. On top of it they have recently burned/deprecated their old API. Here's the [new API description](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/). You'll need to get some watsone credentials first.

You should be able to consume the [v1 Converstaions API](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1) like any other RESTful API. I like [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) for this task.

```
namespace WhatsOn
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Flurl;
    using Flurl.Http;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TalkToWatson().Wait();
        }

        public static async Task TalkToWatson()
        {
            var baseurl = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api";
            var workspace = "25dfa8a0-0263-471b-8980-317e68c30488";
            var username = "...get your own...";
            var password = "...get your own...";
            var context = null as object;
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var message = new { input = new { text = input }, context };

            var resp = await baseurl
                .AppendPathSegments("v1", "workspaces", workspace, "message")
                .SetQueryParam("version","2016-11-21")
                .WithBasicAuth(username, password)
                .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                .PostJsonAsync(message);

            var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var answer = new
            {
                intents = default(object),
                entities = default(object),
                input = default(object),
                output = new
                {
                    text = default(string[])
                },
                context = default(object)
            };

            answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, answer);

            var output = answer?.output?.text?.Aggregate(
                new StringBuilder(),
                (sb,l) => sb.AppendLine(l),
                sb => sb.ToString());

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine($"{resp.StatusCode}: {output}");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call ANY of the Watson Cloud services with the REST interface, as shown in the previous answer.  Just be sure to format the JSON payload correctly, all of the information that you need is in the [Conversation API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/).

That being said, there is a [SDK for .NET](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk#installing-the-watson-net-standard-sdk) though it may still be immature. You can go out and see all of the current SDKs and utilities out on the [Watson Developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud?cm_mc_uid=53633831765514842358764&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1484235876) out on GitHub.

Comment: and what about this?: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk#installing-the-watson-net-standard-sdk.